# Getting HTML drop down list value from code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have drop down list and asp button in my page like this:

```
<select id="select1" >
   <option value="smiley.gif">Smiley</option>
   <option value="angry.gif">Angry</option>
   <option value="stickman.gif">Stickman</option>
</select>
  <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" onclick="btnSubmit_Click" />
```

Once the button is clicked, I need to get the selected value from the drop down list and save it in the session. 
But when the list is changed, it should not reload the page (Simply I don't need to use `runat="server"`).
How to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the value from the Request object.

Edit, thanks to comment by @Péter, add name property to the select element:

```
<select id="select1" name="select1">
   <option value="smiley.gif">Smiley</option>
   <option value="angry.gif">Angry</option>
   <option value="stickman.gif">Stickman</option>
</select>
```

In code-behind:

```
var selectedOption = Request["select1"];
```

Though, if you are using asp.net I suggest you use the server version (runat=server) of the select and thereby could access the value directly from a Select object in code-behind.

To avoid postback you can set AutoPostback=false, the following solution would not post back when selecting a value in the drop down list. And you get the bonus of type safety etc by using an asp.net control for your drop down:

```
<asp:DropDownList id="select1" runat="server" AutoPostback="False">
   <asp:ListItem Value="smiley.gif" Text="Smiley"/>
   <asp:ListItem Value="angry.gif" Text="Angry"/>
   <asp:ListItem Value="stickman.gif" Text="Stickman"/>
</asp:DropDownList>
  <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" onclick="btnSubmit_Click" />
```

In code-behind:

```
var selectedOption = select1.SelectedValue;
```

Comment: This doesn't work `[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]`. I clearly mention, that i no need to reload the page once change the selection.

Comment: Also set the name attribute to select1.

Comment: var selectedOption = Request.QueryString["select1"]; this is wrong. How can you get it form QueryString?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set name of the html control, and then you can get it from Request Object.

```
<select id="select1" name="myselect" >
   <option value="smiley.gif">Smiley</option>
   <option value="angry.gif">Angry</option>
   <option value="stickman.gif">Stickman</option>
</select>
```

Inside you button click event handler:

```
string selection = Request["myselect"];
```