# How to access the selected item in a Droplist in Code Behind?

Tags: c#, sitecore

I have a Droplist in one of my templates which is populated with some content items. In Code Behind I want to access the selected Item in the Droplist. I searched Google, but haven't found anything.

Anyone can show me how to access a Droplist and get its selected Item in C#?

Comment: When you say Droplist, you're referring to a ComboBox?  Also, have you made any attempts at this already, and if you can you post the code you've tried?

Comment: I think you are working on Sitecore. To get the information, you need to use Sitecore library to access DropList data type. Most answers are about just plain ASP.Net. Is it right???

Comment: Based on your question, I've provided an answer assuming you specifically want to access the selected item and not just the selected value held in the droplist field.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer isn't quite as straight-forward as you think.  Sitecore has two field types that allow users to select an item from a list of items:  `Droplist` and `Droplink`.

Droplist fields store the *name* of the item selected by the user, but not a reference to the item itself.  This is useful only for when you have an incredibly basic selection and know you will never need to provide more information.

Droplink fields store the *ID* of the item selected by the user, and can be accessed by doing the following:

```
public Item GetSelectedItemFromDroplinkField(Item item, string fieldName)
{
    ReferenceField field = item.Fields[fieldName];
    if (field == null || field.TargetItem == null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    return field.TargetItem;
}
```

My suggestion would be changing the field type to a Droplink, if it's a simple change for you to make, and it won't impact existing content.  If you can't do this, then the following code might help you out:

```
public Item GetSelectedItemFromDroplistField(Item item, string fieldName)
{
    Field field = item.Fields[fieldName];
    if (field == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(field.Value))
    {
        return null;
    }

    var fieldSource = field.Source ?? string.Empty;
    var selectedItemPath = fieldSource.TrimEnd('/') + "/" + field.Value;
    return item.Database.GetItem(selectedItemPath);
}
```

It works by taking the name of the selected item, and appending it to the `source` attribute (which you set on the template).  It's far from perfect, but it's along the right lines and should get you on the right track.

Comment: Definitely agree with using Droplink instead of Droplist - The selection of your Droplist might not work anymore when you rename an item that's in that list, or when the location of those items changes

Comment: Yes, absolutely @Trayek; personally I almost never use droplists as they're limited and - for the reasons you gave - quite fiddly to change later on.  Droplinks are almost always a better option

Answer (score 0):

You can select by dropdown ID

```
dropdownID.SelectedValue.ToString()
```

Answer (score 0):

page.aspx:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTipoDocumento" runat="server">
  <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="0">Select</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem Value="1">Element 1</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem Value="1">Element 2</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

page.aspx.cs(code behind):

```
ddlTipoDocumento.SelectedItem.Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can test

> var selectedOption = select1.SelectedValue;

Visit [Getting HTML drop down list value from code behind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21306051/getting-html-drop-down-list-value-from-code-behind)

Answer (score 0):

you can access the value with the property SelectedValue.
for example: `var Value = DropDownList1.SelectedValue` but you nned to enable autopostback on the control like this

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" autopostback="true">
```

Answer (score 0):

mark up

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddListTest" runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem Value="item1" Selected="True">Item 1</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="item2">Item 2</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="item3">Item 3</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

C# code

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ddListTest.ClearSelection();
        ddListTest.Items.FindByValue("item2").Selected = true;
    }
}
```

this may help you

[for more info](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/776840/Why-DropDownList-SelectedValue-Does-Not-Work-Insid)

Answer (score 0):

The value of a #Sitecore Droplist field type is a string, and it is the name of the item that is selected.

To get the value out, you can simply do item["MyField"]

This may be a duplicate question - [How to use Droplist types in Sitecore template fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28055434/sitecore-droplist-type-in-template-field)

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
myDropDownList.SelectedIndex = 1;
```

or if you want to read the value:

```
myDropDownList.Text == "test"
```

ASP:

```
                   <asp:DropDownList ID="myDropDownList" runat="server" ViewStateMode="Enabled" class="sys_small">
                            <asp:ListItem Value="test1" Text="test1"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="test2" Text="test2"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="test3" Text="test3"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="test4" Text="test4"></asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access sitecore field as:
 
Item item = Sitecore.Context.Item;
item.Fields["Droplink"].Value;