# Sitecore how to get a Droplist or Droplink selected item's both Id and Value?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8.2

```
var item = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem('xxx');
```

Now how can I get both its id and value? I've tried use `item.Fields[""]` , but only got an empty string, not sure why.

Comment: https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/93/sitecore-experience-manager/access-droplink,-droptree,-and-grouped-droplink-fields.html

Answer (score 0):

What Sitecore field type you are using "Droplink" or "DropList".

Please see if below solution helps:

[How to access the selected item in a Droplist in Code Behind?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29541846/how-to-access-the-selected-item-in-a-droplist-in-code-behind)